# Unable to create plugin for Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product

Tags: magento2, plugin, product-page

I seem to be unable to create a plugin for the named class.

The plugin is executed, but then the static files on product pages do not get deployed in developer mode and I get an error in the `system.log` file saying that a less mixin could not be found. The `exception.log` does not show anything.

The same happens when I create a preference for that class.

Funny enough, if I add my code changes (replace `getById()` with a collection, see below) directly into the core file, everything works fine.

Using version 2.1.8.

Here is my code:

**etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product">
        <plugin name="Namespace_Module" type="Namespace\Module\Helper\Catalog\ProductPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Helper/Catalog/ProductPlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Helper\Catalog;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product as OriginalProduct;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ModelProduct;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager;

class ProductPlugin
{

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(EventManager $eventManager, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession, \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry, CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * replace getbyId() with product collection for better performance
     *
     * @param OriginalProduct $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param mixed $productId
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View $controller
     * @param mixed $params
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     * @return boolean|\Magento\Framework\DataObject
     */
    public function aroundInitProduct(OriginalProduct $subject, callable $proceed, $productId, $controller, $params = null)
    {
        // Prepare data for routine
        if (! $params) {
            $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        }

        // Init and load product
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_controller_product_init_before', [
            'controller_action' => $controller,
            'params' => $params
        ]);

        if (! $productId) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
            $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $productId)
                ->addMediaGalleryData()
                ->addOptionsToResult()
                ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
            if (! $collection->count()) {
                throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Product not found with id $1', $productId));
            }
            $product = $collection->getFirstItem();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }

        if (! $subject->canShow($product)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (! in_array($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId(), $product->getWebsiteIds())) {
            return false;
        }

        // Load product current category
        $categoryId = $params->getCategoryId();
        if (! $categoryId && $categoryId !== false) {
            $lastId = $this->_catalogSession->getLastVisitedCategoryId();
            if ($product->canBeShowInCategory($lastId)) {
                $categoryId = $lastId;
            }
        } elseif (! $product->canBeShowInCategory($categoryId)) {
            $categoryId = null;
        }

        if ($categoryId) {
            try {
                $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $category = null;
            }
            if ($category) {
                $product->setCategory($category);
                $this->_coreRegistry->register('current_category', $category);
            }
        }

        // Register current data and dispatch final events
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('current_product', $product);
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('product', $product);

        try {
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_controller_product_init_after', [
                'product' => $product,
                'controller_action' => $controller
            ]);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical($e);
            return false;
        }

        return $product;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I see, and it MIGHT be the cause of your problem and it might not be, is still a problem in and of itself.

In your "around" observer, you never call `$proceed($productId, $controller, $params)`. By never making this call, you prevent all other plugins on this method from firing. It's a possible cause to your issue but you'll have to test.

To test, comment out the content of your function and simply do `return $proceed($productId, $controller, $params);`, flush cache, and see if the problem goes away. If that doesn't pan out, then it's something else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually tested with proceed, and it still did not work. I went for another way. I accept this answer tho as it's a valid point.